# You have no items in your shopping cart. error using Magento 2

Tags: php, magento

> Shopping Cart
>
> You have no items in your shopping cart.
>
> Click here to continue shopping.

No items in cart message when place something in cart on my website.
My cookie limit is 86400

Answer (score 0):

Remove cache and use indexing

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Then deploy again:

```
rm -rf var/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
chmod -R 7777 var pub/static
```

If it will not work then check your minicart.phtml and also the UI components.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting checkout page

product is not adding to checkout page then use in commandline

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush